# How to use AWS S3 credentials without security vulnerability?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, android-security

My Android App using AWS S3 to store images. below is the version details I'm using.

```
def aws_version = "2.16.+"
implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:$aws_version"
implementation ("com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:$aws_version") { transitive = true }
```

Currently, The way I'm accessing the secret key and access key through BuildConfig variables.
I found this method [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Storing-Secret-Keys-in-Android).

```
BasicAWSCredentials cred = new BasicAWSCredentials(BuildConfig.key, BuildConfig.secret);//Access Key and Secret Key
AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(cred, Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1));
AwsUploadFile.Companion.uploadFile(this, client, file, shopName, transferListener);
```

Now I've received the mail which says

> Your app(s) expose Amazon Web Services credentials.

Now I wanted to know what I have done wrong.
and what is the correct way of storing the AWS S3 secret key and access key?

One important point which might help you answer this question,

- once I have used the secret key and access key as hardcoded string and push these changes over to our private git project. after realizing my mistake I changed the implementation and now using the BuildConfig method as explained above. I don't know if this could be the case for exposed credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways:

1. AWS Security Token Service (AWS STS)
2. AWS Cognito
3. AWS Amplify
4. Android Key Store

Here is the official documentation about using AWS credentials for authentication in the mobile apps: [Authenticating Users of AWS Mobile Applications with a Token Vending Machine](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/authenticating-users-of-aws-mobile-applications-with-a-token-vending-machine/)

Comment: I am still confused as to what to do next. can you guide me for the second option? that is AWS Cognito I was trying but unable to understand.

Comment: @Vijay, Try this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/using-android-sdk-with-amazon-cognito-your-user-pools/

Comment: @Vijay: Check this out as well: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/expert-aws-development/9781788477581/4b6cd606-55b4-4e2e-a375-1f95341288e9.xhtml

Comment: @Vijay, If you liked the answer and it worked for you, kindly approve it and upvote it as well as recommended by Stack Overflow.

Comment: I like the answer but this doesn't help me so I tried a totally different approach.

Comment: @Vijay, Kindly share that approach as answer so that others can get benefit by following it in the future.

Comment: @abdullahkhawer I have created an API to fetch aws credentials and I am using that credentials to upload video. it will work?